# Seeking demographic information for Non-US regions

Tags: demographics, census, global

I seek CSVs of census / other demographic data for countries around the world which are broken down as fine grained a manner as possible.

As an example of something close but not quite, the Statistics Bureau of Japan puts out these maps (https://www.stat.go.jp/english/data/chiri/map/c_koku/2015.html) but not the raw data (as far as I can find).

Where do I find similar data for as many countries as possible in a raw format?

Answer (score 1):

For Australia - take a look at The Australian Bureau of Statistics [ABS](https://www.abs.gov.au) where Census data can be sourced (multiple data sets including longitudinal data - head to [Data packs](https://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/D3310114.nsf/Home/2016%20DataPacks)). For spatial data head to Geoscience Australia [GA](http://www.ga.gov.au) or [Data.GOV.AU](https://data.gov.au)

Answer (score 1):

https://international.ipums.org/international/ has a lot of data from censuses from many countries, all conveniently stored in the same place and with a common interface. It's not very different from what you could get by going to official sources in each country.

Answer (score 1):

For India, [Census Data of india](https://censusindia.gov.in/pca/cdb_pca_census/cd_block.html) contains the district level census data of census work done in 2011 in CSV file format. This is the Government of India website. Each state in India is divided into various districts.